# Read specific values from a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've got an application that writes a cookie for that domain. There is a lot of information in this cookie, but nothing sensitive. One of the values it stores is "DisplayFullName" which I would like to retrieve.

I've been searching for a while, and found many code examples that allow you to read a cookie (all values in it), but nothing that specifically allows you to read a specific value. I did find a jquery example, but that looked like it was looping through the values. However my cms does not have jquery installed so would like to do it the old fashioned way.

This is the code I have to read the cookie, which seems to be working fine. I just need to read the specific value. Can someone help or point me in the right direction please.

```
function getCookie(name)
{
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}

alert(getCookie("ecm"));
```

I want to eventually add the DisplayFullName to the src of an iframe id I have called MyIframe as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for you. It just loops over the cookies looking for the name you pass in.

```
function getCookieByName(name) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";"),
        yerCookie = null,
        cookiePair;

    for (var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        cookiePair = cookies[i].split("=");
        if (cookiePair[0].trim() === name) {
            yerCookie = cookiePair.slice(1).join("=");
            break;
        }
    }

    return yerCookie;
}
```

or you can use this nice function cribbed from [here](https://gist.github.com/remy/350433#file-gistfile1-js-L17-L33) :

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=",
        ca = document.cookie.split(';'),
        i, c;

    for (i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you have the ecm cookie, parse it with the following:

```
function getECMCookieProperty(ecmCookie, prop) {

    if (!ecmCookie) {
        return undefined;
    }

    var props = ecmCookie.split("&"),
        result = null,
        propList;

    for (var i=0;i<props.length;i++){
        propList = props[i].split("=");
        if (propList[0] === prop) {
            result = unescape(propList[1]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

to use these, do:

```
var ecmCookie = getCookieByName("ecm");
var displayFullName = getECMCookieProperty(ecmCookie, "DisplayFullName");
alert(displayFullName)
```

Comment: Hi Andbdrew, I've tried accessing the cookie with alert(getCookieByName("DisplayFullName")); - however I'm not getting the response I want. Should I be doing something else to access the DisplayFullName parameter from the cookie thats called ecm?

Comment: @JK36 can you post `document.cookie`? If the cookie looks like `"DisplayFullName=Foo;"`, then `getCookieByName("DisplayFullName")` will return `Foo`

Comment: Not sure this is what you want, but this is what is contained in my ecm cookie DisplayFullName=My%20Name&username=xUser1&dm=www.my.domain.name.com&DefaultLanguage=2057&NavLanguage=2057&SiteLanguage=2057&TimeZone=GMT Standard Time&SubType=&ContType=-1

Comment: @JK36 what do you see when you type `console.log(document.cookie)` in your browser's js console?

Comment: ecm=DisplayFullName=My%20Name&username=xUser1&dm=www.my.domain.name.com&DefaultLangu‌​age=2057&NavLanguage=2057&SiteLanguage=2057&TimeZone=GMT Standard Time&SubType=&ContType=-1; ektron_analytics_overlay=mode=none; RadEditorGlobalSerializeCookie=[ctl00_ctl00_cp1_ContentBlock1_ContentDesignerModules]-[]#[content_teaser_ContentDesignerModules]-[]#[content_teaser_ContentDesignerToolbars]-[]#[content_html_ContentDesignerModules]-[]#[content_html_ContentDesignerToolbars]-[]#;

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you would be not to use cookies at all. Use the `localStorage` interface, which has a *much* more user-friendly syntax.

For instance:

```
localStorage['ecm'] = 'some value';
alert(localStorage['ecm']);
```

Since it's just a Javascript object, you can also use the dot notation:

```
localStorage.ecm = 'some value';
alert(localStorage.ecm);
```

This is only natively present in modern browsers. If backwards-compatibility is important, there are various shims available, e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/remy/350433), which make the functionality available to all browsers using old-fashioned cookies behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is its not my application that generates the cookie. Its a thirdparty cms system on our server. I just want to pass the displayname over to another system